# How to add a button using kendo toolbar?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid where i have Kendo Tabstrip in toolbar so outside this kendo tabstrip I want to add an export button that should work for all tabstrips. I have added a button but its not appearing in the grid. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Please advise

So far I have tried this:

```
toolbar: [
        {
            template: kendo.template('<kendo-tabstrip><ul><li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultAllTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border"  ng-click="getAllSubCategories()">All</a></li>')
        },
        {
            template: kendo.template('<li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultPendingTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border" ng-click="getPendingSubCategories()">Pending Review</a></li>')
        },
        {
            template: kendo.template('<li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultReviewTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border" ng-click="getReviewedSubCategories()">Reviewed</a></li></ul><kendo-tabstrip>')
        },
        {
        template: ' <button class="k-grid-excel pull-right btn btn-default btn-sm">Export to Excel</button>'
        }
    ],
    excel: {
      fileName: 'Subcategory.xlsx',
      proxyURL: '/third-party-management/rest/xls/download',
      allPages:true,
      filterable: true
  },
```

Comment: Is it being at least created on the dom?

Comment: yes it created on dom

Comment: But where it is located? Is hidden under some other element or under the tabstrip?